# What's wrong with my code? Where do i put my line?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

In the following code, I want to make a small screen that has a piece of text in it using `JFrame`. Why does not this code work?

```
package notepad;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Notepad extends JFrame{

public Notepad(){
    setTitle("Notepad");
    setSize(250, 250);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
}

 public static void main(String[] args){
     new Notepad();
     System.out.println("Hello World!", 75, 75);
 }
}
```

If you look at the `System.out.println("Hello World!", 75, 75);` why does the 75, 75 not work? How do I make the text go there?

Comment: There is no such method overload for println, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: System.out.println writes to the console, that's it. You aren't doing anything to put the message in your Notepad.

Comment: if you do want to write to the console, maybe you are confusing println with format: `System.out.format("Hello World! %d %d", 75, 75);`

Comment: I get the feeling that you saw code that kind-of sort-of looks like the code you're trying to use, but aren't 100% sure of what the previous code looked like or what your current code should do. Perhaps you're remembering code that tried to draw text on the Screen using a Graphics object, such as `Graphics#drawString(...)`, since this method does in fact take a String and two ints for its parameters. One thing you'll want to do (that we all currently do) is to not rely on the dim recesses of your memory to call up code, but instead to use the available references to be sure of your code.

Comment: Again, no insult intended as my memory is probably a lot dimmer than yours. Just be sure to get very familiar with the [Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html) and the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/).

Answer (score 3):

`printLn` outputs a line of text to the console window.  To put text into the UI window you would need to create a `JLabel` and add it to your `JFrame`.

```
public Notepad(){
    setTitle("Notepad");
    setResizable(false);

    add(new JLabel("This will be on your UI window"))

    setVisible(true);
    pack(); 
}
```